# What happens when you pull in on a rotating object?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, free-body-diagram, string, centripetal-force

I was wondering how rotating objects would behave if we pulled them inwards DURING rotation?

For example-

If I was initially spinning a rock attached to a string in a uniform circular motion
and then (at $t=0$) the string starts decreasing length at a **net inward velocity** of '$v$'
then what would be equation and time period of the movement till the string length becomes 0?
The diagram at $t=0$ would look something like this:

[image]

I tried coming up with an equation myself, taking center as (0,0):

$$x=vt\cos\left(\frac{2 \pi t}{T} \right)$$

$$y=vt\sin\left(\frac{2 \pi t}{T} \right)$$

but since the time period ($T$) is variable (due to decreasing radius) I don't think it's correct

as far as my intuition goes there would be a certain spiral inwards path followed but I can not understand how to find the time period? do I even have the right approach?

Note: Please don't mark this as a h.w. question I'm just trying to understand it intuitively
and if the question seems unclear just let me know I'll edit it instead of closing it,

I'm losing sleep over this query